# Is it possible to concat logs with the same fields in fluentd

Tags: parsing, concatenation, grouping, postfix-mta, fluentd

We are analyzing the postfix log. The postfix log follows the pattern:

```
<time> <host> <processor> <queueid> message.
```

For example:

```
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 header X-SF-SENDER: X.com.
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG header X-SF-SENDER: abc.com.
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 header x-msg-id: 123455.
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG header x-msg-id: 54321d.
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG to: recipient@abc.com, status: bounced.
...
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 to: recipient@x.com, status: sent.
...
```

We want to group the logs with the `queueid`. That means if two logs have the same `queueid`, we should concat the message. So for the above example, we want just two final message:

Message 1:

```
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 header X-SF-SENDER: X.com.
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 header x-msg-id: 123455.
<time> <host> <processor> 090991193 to: recipient@x.com, status: sent.
...
```

Message 2:

```
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG header X-SF-SENDER: abc.com.
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG header x-msg-id: 54321d.
<time> <host> <processor> ABCDDEFG to: recipient@abc.com, status: bounced.
...
```

I am looking in to the plugin: https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat, but I don't quite understand the meaning of the options.

Could anybody give an example of configuration how to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: What is your complete use case? Why do you want to aggregate such logs? Even if you concatenate all logs with the same `queueid`, how do you want to consume those i.e. `match` section?